# How to show a jquery dialogue box as alert on clicking a link from menu bar.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a menu bar which contains links for web pages. Now I want to add a login form with username and password with submit button in dilaogue box with locked screen on clicking of particular web pages. Its a kind of double login authentication.. As soon as log in submit button is clicked it should go to database to check the entered credentials and if it is correct will lead or show the clicked link..

To check the credentials I have made ajax call to server side code.. but I dont know how to add dialogue box and after success lead to required clicked page...

Here is my ajax call code..

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'logincredit',
    async:false,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
    }                
});
```

Please guys help me ..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: You can open dialog in success function.Are you asking for the code to open the dialog window

Answer (score 0):

You can add dialog script inside the success function.

like this

```
success: function(data){
if(data.d==true)
//show dialog code
else
//show something else

}
```